# why this abstract class can be instantiated？

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Since "abstract class" can't be instantiated， why this MD5 class below can be instantiated?
`MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();`

Who can help me to understand the abstract class.

Comment: [That's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5.create?view=net-7.0) a (factory-)method, it can instantiate whatever it wants. You can even provide a factory for an interface. "Creates an instance of the default implementation of the MD5 hash algorithm"

Comment: Because that is a `static` method, and internally it doesn't create an instance of `MD5`, it actually returns a `MD5Cng` or a `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`

Comment: Did you use `new MD5()`? No. All you know is that `Create` creates *something* that can be cast to `MD5`.

Comment: The underlying principle is that you can always assign a reference to a derived object to a reference to the base class: The derived *is-a* base, it can stand for the base wherever one is used or needed.

Comment: @DavidG It returns *a reference* to `MD5`! (Which just happens to be pointing to to an object of type `MD5Cng` or `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`...)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That is a poor choice of words. It returns a value which is of *type* `MD5` which is actually a derived type of one of the ones I mention above. Also, to say it is pointing to something else is very confusing.

Comment: @DavidG "It returns a value": I can assure you it does nothing of that sort.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica All methods return a value or they are `void`, what are you on about?

Comment: @DavidG The only values returned in C# are primitive types, structs and references. MD5 is a class; the return value therefore is a reference; specifically, a reference to an MD5. (Yeah, C# often refers to references as "values"; of course, pointers are values, too.) The `MD5Cng` is not returned at all, it stays where it was created. Of course I'm not telling you anything new here, so this is more an argument about terminology. But specifically when we talk to beginners about polymorphism it's essential to point out that no object is passed around here at all.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Then you need to adjust your language to match how the [**official docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#return-values) talk about it. [They all use value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcFKP.png) to talk about "the thing returned from a method". You are confusing the discussion around value type and reference types, which nobody mentioned.

Comment: But I'm done with this conversation now, it is very silly.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a constructor, meaning the abstractness of the class is still intact

Abstract classes are like a mirror of interfaces in a way. While an interface declares common methods, the abstract class may also *implement* these common methods. Ideally, an interface also should not have state but this is slightly complicated by C#'s properties so it may not look at "strict" as in ex. Java. Classes may implement multiple interfaces, but may only inherit from (or extend) from one abstract class.
Think of an apple as extending an abstract fruit class, while the apple tree implements a fruit tree interface (which probably extends tree, plant, etc etc interfaces)

The `.Create()` method's documentation states that it ["Allows specific implementations of this abstract class to be created"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5.create?view=net-7.0) which is what you would call a "factory pattern".

Pause, `.Create()` explicitly states that it returns the default implementation, there is no sort of factory pattern actually at work here

Digging deeper into the docs, we see that the now obsolete `.Create(string)` overload was the true factory pattern, and would rout to a specific implementation.

My guess is that, rather than deprecate the entire method in favor of another (which would probably end up breaking code), MS reasoned to keep the original method that returns the default implementation.

So technically it is not actually really a factory pattern, but its overload was in the past, and for the sake of legacy code they kept the original and marked the overload as obsolete rather than deprecate the entire method

Comment: Nothing wrong, but i think the question has a different scope. I think OP doesnt even understand that the `Create` method is not the constructor. Yes, the `Create` method is a factory method and i don't think that it's technically not really a factory pattern. Both `Create` methods are static methods where the one without arguments actually calls the other, so either both are true factory methods or none. Imo there's no difference, even if "true" factory methods(gang of four) implement abstract methods in sub-classes to use polymorphism. Static create-methods are also factory methods.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the clarifications! I am taking a look at the [source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/MD5.cs,dbd8d3af8cb2e795) out of curiosity and what i see is `public static new MD5 Create() => new Implementation();` which returns the impl directly via its default ctor, vs `public static new MD5? Create(string algName) => (MD5?)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(algName);` which is more of a the "classic" factory look to it. So maybe both are factories, assuming we let it slide that the parameter-less overload gives produces 1 possibility